# Plot a Pie figure inside a every Bubble of a Bubble Chart using Excel?

Tags: macos, excel, plot, pie-chart, bubble-chart

-Office for Mac. I have the following Bubble chart :

[image]

I would like to insert a small Pie figure inside each of these bubbles to represent a specific value. How is this possible through Excel ?

Comment: You could use the same method I suggested for your other bubble chart question, in this case making pie charts, and resizing and overlaying them by hand.

Comment: Please answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic method you can use is to create pie charts for each bubble, modify the formatting of the pie charts to eliminate everything but the pies from view (turn off borders, any text labeling, backgrounds, etc.), and resize and overlay the pies over the corresponding bubble. After you've done all the bubbles, you may want to group all the elements together to avoid inadvertent misalignment of the overlays.